# What data type is needed for a meta-analysis?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, metafor

I have a student who has compiled field data from agricultural studies across parts of Africa. She wants to conduct a meta-analysis to determine if cropping system type is having an impact on crop yield, and has been exploring the *metafor* package. A sample of the data is below.

I have no experience with meta-analyses so I am not sure if it is possible given the dataset. The values are means, there are no controls, and often the study authors don't report standard deviation. Can a meta-analysis be conducted on this data? If not, what other information is needed?

Many thanks!

Nic

````
    data <-structure(list(Study = c(4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                    4L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                                    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
                                                    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
                                                    17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
                                                    17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
                                                    17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
                                                    18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
                           ), Crop.combination = c("maize-beans", "maize-beans", "maize-beans", 
                                                   "maize-beans", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", "maize-cowpea", 
                                                   "maize-cowpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", 
                                                   "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", 
                                                   "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", 
                                                   "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", 
                                                   "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", 
                                                   "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", "maize-pigeonpea", 
                                                   "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", 
                                                   "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", 
                                                   "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "cowpea", 
                                                   "cowpea", "cowpea", "cowpea", "cowpea", "cowpea", "cowpea", "cowpea", 
                                                   "cowpea", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", "maize", 
                                                   "maize", "maize", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", 
                                                   "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", 
                                                   "maize-soybean", "maize-soybean", "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea", 
                                                   "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea", 
                                                   "pigeonpea", "pigeonpea"), Cropping.System = c("Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Intercrop", 
                                                                                                  "Intercrop", "Intercrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", "Monocrop", 
                                                                                                  "Monocrop", "Monocrop"), Yield.kg.ha = c(2400L, 3800L, 4720L, 
                                                                                                                                           2260L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 600L, 650L, 
                                                                                                                                           670L, 690L, 750L, 750L, 750L, 750L, 790L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 
                                                                                                                                           880L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 1000L, 1000L, 1400L, 2200L, 2000L, 1200L, 
                                                                                                                                           1200L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1750L, 1750L, 2000L, 2000L, 2100L, 
                                                                                                                                           2100L, 2100L, 2200L, 2280L, 2600L, 2600L, 2800L, 2890L, 2900L, 
                                                                                                                                           4750L, 4750L, 5900L, 6000L, 1800L, 1800L, 9450L, 9020L, 1700L, 
                                                                                                                                           1800L, 1800L, 2000L, 4700L, 1800L, 2000L, 4700L, 2000L, 500L, 
                                                                                                                                           1900L, 5800L, 800L, 800L, 2800L, 2600L, 2800L, 2800L, 1200L, 
                                                                                                                                           1200L, 1300L, 5800L, 1500L, 5890L, 4950L, 1200L, 1400L, 1800L, 
                                                                                                                                           1200L, 2100L, 3200L, 2300L, 2900L, 3600L, 500L, 670L, 750L, 800L, 
                                                                                                                                           1000L, 1150L, 1200L, 1250L, 2100L, 500L, 600L, 750L, 850L, 900L, 
                                                                                                                                           900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 2000L, 2000L, 2100L, 
                                                                                                                                           2100L, 2200L, 2300L, 2400L, 2600L, 1600L, 1700L, 2500L, 2800L, 
                                                                                                                                           1800L, 2800L, 3400L, 3600L, 2100L, 3900L, 4500L, 4900L, 1800L, 
                                                                                                                                           1800L, 2100L, 2300L, 2600L, 3100L, 3400L, 250L, 420L, 780L, 1140L, 
                                                                                                                                           4510L, 4690L, 400L, 500L, 700L, 700L, 1000L, 1000L, 1400L, 1600L, 
                                                                                                                                           1700L, 2750L, 2800L, 2900L, 2920L, 3750L, 3800L, 4000L, 4500L, 
                                                                                                                                           4800L, 300L, 600L, 800L, 1000L, 1800L, 1800L, 1400L, 1600L, 1300L, 
                                                                                                                                           1200L, 900L, 1800L, 1900L, 2700L, 4800L, 3700L, 4250L, 4000L, 
                                                                                                                                           4190L, 4200L, 2650L, 3000L, 2500L, 2250L, 3000L, 2500L, 4900L, 
                                                                                                                                           4000L, 5700L, 5600L, 1180L, 1900L, 1100L, 2800L, 3800L, 2000L, 
                                                                                                                                           3000L, 2800L, 2800L, 2700L, 1800L, 2000L, 1900L, 1150L, 1500L, 
                                                                                                                                           2100L, 3000L, 2150L, 2000L, 1900L, 2460L, 4330L, 1470L, 3200L, 
                                                                                                                                           2280L, 730L, 1340L, 1320L, 1090L, 2700L, 1970L, 1750L, 1870L, 
                                                                                                                                           1950L, 1250L, 1600L, 1800L, 2100L, 1800L, 2800L, 4000L, 2800L, 
                                                                                                                                           3600L, 4500L, 600L, 700L, 750L, 800L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1200L, 
                                                                                                                                           1390L, 1500L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -249L
                                                                                                                                           )) ```
````

Comment: Definitely, we have to take yield in control. SD is not generally reported, so you have to take the number of replications and calculate weight. See equation 2 in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-09742-9.pdf)

Comment: ***META-DATA!*** (Sorry, I could not resist the pun. :)

Comment: Why do you think you need a control group here? What exactly is the scientific question which makes you think so?